# Where to put javascript file for this specific plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement ***phone number verification*** in my app with [***prove-ruby***](https://github.com/getprove/prove-ruby) and integrating its API as per the steps listed in the [***docs***](https://getprove.com/docs#plugin).

So, I followed the steps and created `index.html` and `verified.html` in ***public*** folder and copied the content. Now I'm confused where does `app.js` file goes(i.e., where to put it).

Should it go to `/vendor/assets/javascripts` or should I create a new file with the name `app.js` in ***public*** folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put application specific code into `app.js` which just uses and configures the library, it should go into `/app/assets/javascripts`:

> `app/assets` is for assets that are owned by the application, such as
>   custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: And with the name `app.js`?

Comment: Wait. `app.js` just mean `application.js`?

Comment: You should name it according to its contents and you have to reference it in your manifest file (`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`) to have it included in your default application javascript (`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`)

Comment: No, `application.js` is your manifest file where you should just reference all javascript files your application needs.

Comment: Ok. So I can name it as `prove.js` and reference it like `//= require prove`. thats it right?

Comment: You can do it like that, yes.

Comment: Ok. I will check and accept your answer if works. Thanks. :)